# Is there an equivalent of "after_sign_in_path_for" for user edit/commit?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Running Rails 3.2.1 with devise-2.0.4.gem.

Is there an equivalent redirect configuration for user/commit similar to "after_sign_in_path_for"?  In production, I have to use HTTPS so the URL for "Edit User" is https://www.xyz.com/users/edit.  When I click "Update", the correct update takes place but then Devise redirects to "http://www.xyz.com/users/edit" which results in error loading page since HTTP is not supported in production.

I had a similar issue with sign in/out (http://groups.google.com/group/plataformatec-devise/browse_thread/thread/5fafb2a8c90f1d43) which I solved by defining after_sign_in_path_for.  But I don't see such similar config for user edit/commit.

Then I tried to force HTTPS in routes.rb:
    devise_scope :user do
      get "users/edit", :to => "users/registrations#edit", :as => :edit_user, :protocol => "https"
      put "users/commit", :controller => "users/registrations", :action => 'commit', :as => :commit_user, :protocol => "https"
    end

And see this in rake routes:
    edit_user   GET    /users/edit(.:format)    users/ registrations#edit  {:protocol=>"https"}
    commit_user PUT    /users/commit(.:format)  users/registrations#commit {:protocol=>"https"}

But Devise still routes to HTTP after the update action.

Looking at registrations_controller.rb, I see several instances of
    redirect_to edit_user_path
So as a work around, I change it to
 
    redirect_to https://www.xyz.com/user/edit

And that is working.  But I'm not sure if this is the correct approach.